# Smarty file exists syntax

Tags: image, file, syntax, smarty, exists

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? It is defaulting to my else statement even if a file does exist.

{assign var="wine" value="`$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT`/images/thumbs/`$link.ID`-300x225.png"}
{if file_exists($wine)}
File Exists!
{else}
File does not exist!
{/if}

Although you can't see the code, I do have backticks (backtick)$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT(backtick) and here (backtick)$link.ID(backtick)

When I use it like this it works but not in the example above:

```
<img src="{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/images/thumbs/{$link.ID}-300x225.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: don't forget to answer your own question and mark as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced:
$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT

With the absolute path and it worked.
/home/user/public_html/etc...

Note:
$link.ID I put in backticks(``) otherwise it threw an error.